# Open SpringBoot resource as UTF-8 file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, utf-8

I hav this piece of code to open a file, but I like to know if it is possible to open it UTF-8 file

```
Resource usersResource = new ClassPathResource("users.csv");

@Before
public void setUp() throws IOException {
    usersResource.getInputStream());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe InputStreamReader can solve this for you with something like:

```
new InputStreamReader(usersResource.getInputStream(), "UTF-8")
```

From https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStreamReader.html:

> An InputStreamReader is a bridge from byte streams to character streams: It reads bytes and decodes them into characters using a specified charset.

Please let me know if this is useful.

-Kaj :)